# Square v2 API - Questions on filtering

Tags: square-connect

When we wrote or initial integration for Square v1 API, there wasn't an option to filter ListOrders by Date

Our questions for v2 api:

In v2, looks like all transactions are housed under the same endpoint.

Okay, we call GET /transactions
  How do we tell what is an order vs. payment vs. refund in the response?

not all payments are generated off an order.  For example, I can do one-off Square transactions on my phone for walk-up customers, which would not have an order associated with it)

Can we filter for orders only?
  Does the Transaction endpoint supports date filtering now?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the documentation for the [v2 Transaction](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2/#type-transaction) object. Refunds and orders are subsets of that object.

Also look at the documentation for the [List Transactions](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2/#endpoint-listtransactions) where you can see that you can currently filter based on times only right now.

If it isn't listed in the documentation, then it probably isn't supported.